# Discord.js: How do I convert timestamp to unix one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So lately I've seen a lot of verified bots using the new "Unix Timestamps". But when I try `<t:${message.author.createdTimestamp}>` it somehow outputs the 50000th year, lol. So that's the problem.

I will really appreciate any form of support because that problem seems controversial to me.

Maybe there is some package or method which can solve this issue. Sadly, I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `<t:###>` will accept seconds only and the timestamp is in milliseconds. You'll need to divide the timestamp by 1000 and as it only accepts integers, either round it (using `Math.round()`, `Math.floor()`, etc.) or convert it to an integer (using `parseInt()`).

Any of these should work and display the date correctly:

```js
<t:${Math.round(message.author.createdTimestamp / 1000)}>
```

```js
<t:${parseInt(message.author.createdTimestamp / 1000, 10)}>
```